# Is it possible to add an extra loglevel in GWT

Tags: gwt

In normal Java it is pretty easy to add your own custom loglevels.
But all the Java ways I know don't work in GWT because GWT has its own implementation of java.util.logging.Level.

Say I want an extra level between SEVERE (1000), and warning (900) --> ERROR (950).

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to sort this out for myself.
In case anyone is interested in this.

What you have to do is create a "super" directory. This on the same level as the "client" directory of your module.

In this directory you create a java.util.logging.Level class with the same content as the one found in the GWT source. But with the added level.

For example :

```
/*
 * Copyright 2010 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
 * use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of
 * the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
 * WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
 * License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
 * the License.
 */

package java.util.logging;

import com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.logging.impl.LevelImpl;
import com.google.gwt.logging.impl.LevelImplNull;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 *  An emulation of the java.util.logging.Level class. See
 *  <a href="http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html">
 *  The Java API doc for details</a>
 */
public class Level implements Serializable {
  private static LevelImpl staticImpl = GWT.create(LevelImplNull.class);
  public static Level ALL = new LevelAll();
  public static Level CONFIG = new LevelConfig();
  public static Level FINE = new LevelFine();
  public static Level FINER = new LevelFiner();
  public static Level FINEST = new LevelFinest();
  public static Level INFO = new LevelInfo();
  public static Level OFF = new LevelOff();
  public static Level EXCEPTION = new LevelException();
  public static Level WARNING = new LevelWarning();
  public static Level ERROR = new LevelError();
  public static Level SEVERE = new LevelSevere();

  private static class LevelAll extends Level {
    @Override public String getName() { return "ALL"; }
    @Override public int intValue() { return Integer.MIN_VALUE; }
  }

  private static class LevelConfig extends Level {
    @Override public String getName() { return "CONFIG"; }
    @Override public int intValue() { return 700; }
  }

  private static class LevelFine extends Level {
    @Override public String getName() { return "FINE"; }
    @Override public int intValue() { return 500; }
  }

  private static class LevelFiner extends Level {
    @Override public String getName() { return "FINER"; }
    @Override public int intValue() { return 400; }
  }

  private static class LevelFinest extends Level {
    @Override public String getName() { return "FINEST"; }
    @Override public int intValue() { return 300; }
  }

  private static class LevelInfo extends Level {
    @Override public String getName() { return "INFO"; }
    @Override public int intValue() { return 800; }
  }

  private static class LevelOff extends Level {
    @Override public String getName() { return "OFF"; }
    @Override public int intValue() { return Integer.MAX_VALUE; }
  }

  private static class LevelException extends Level {
    @Override public String getName() { return "EXCEPTION"; }
    @Override public int intValue() { return 1000; }
  }

  private static class LevelSevere extends Level {
     @Override public String getName() { return "SEVERE"; }
     @Override public int intValue() { return 1000; }
   }

  private static class LevelError extends Level {
     @Override public String getName() { return "ERROR"; }
     @Override public int intValue() { return 950; }
   }

  private static class LevelWarning extends Level {
    @Override public String getName() { return "WARNING"; }
    @Override public int intValue() { return 900; }
  }

  public static Level parse(String name) {
    return staticImpl.parse(name);
  }

  protected Level() { }

  public String getName() {
    return "DUMMY";
  }

  public int intValue() {
    return -1;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return getName();
  }

  /* Not Implemented */
  // public boolean equals(Object ox) {}
  // protected Level(String name, int value, String resourceBundleName) {}
  // public String getLocalizedName() {}
  // public String getResourceBundleName() {}
  // public int  hashCode() {}
}
```

Now you must mark this "super" directory as super source in your gwt.xml

```
<super-source path="super"/>
```

If you are using Eclipse you will have to exclude this super directory from the source path to avoid eclipse giving errors. And add it again as a seperate source path so that eclipse does check the file for errors.

Finally, if you do all this in a sub-module, you must ensure that when compiling your main module, this gets priority over the classes in rt.jar. This can be done by using an endorsed directory when compiling.

Comment: Might I remind you that if it's not your copyright, you can't post it.

Comment: afaik the Apache license permits this, as long as the required notices are included (which I did) ?

Comment: The Apache license permits relicensing of derivative works, but you may not relicense the original work without modifications. To avoid this kind of situation, it can be better to just link to another source of the code.